# Borked OSX Ruby Installation

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I'm not entirely sure when it happened, but attempting to run homebrew on my OSX Mountain Lion machine now yields a strange error:

`` /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- checksums (LoadError) ``

This was noticed after a failed attempt to install RVM with the command:

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    136      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   155
100 13145  100 13145    0     0   6879      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  6879
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0    433      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   551
100 3263k  100 3263k    0     0  1245k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 1467k

Installing RVM to /Users/mike/.rvm/
    Adding rvm PATH line to /Users/mike/.bashrc /Users/mike/.zshrc.
    Adding rvm loading line to /Users/mike/.bash_profile /Users/mike/.zprofile.

  * WARNING: You have RUBYOPT set in your current environment.
    This may cause rubies to not work as you expect them to as it is not supported
    by all of them If errors show up, please try unsetting RUBYOPT first.


# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues run 'rvm requirements' or read 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /Users/mike/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/mike/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# Mike Greiling,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and
#   more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne


rvm 1.19.5 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Skipping `brew update` make sure your formulas are up to date.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
Missing required packages: automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite.
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs for more information.
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
```

I'm unsure if it was this failed attempt to install RVM that borked my default ruby installation or if homebrew itself is corrupted in some way, but I'd like to get homebrew and osx's native ruby install working again if possible.

It may come down to a terminal PATH setting or something, but I'm new to this and have no idea where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by *borked*?

Comment: I mean not working... sorry for the confusion.
  
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=borked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the problem.  The issue appears to have been with homebrew itself.

I ran the following commands to fix it:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ git fetch origin
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

Once that was done `brew update` worked as it should and I re-ran `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` to get rvm installed properly.

Comment: Didn't help.. OS X Lion

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the output:

> RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
>   please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`

If you were following instructions from [rvm site installation instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) it would have worked:

```
\curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rvm get head && rvm reload
```

to update your rvm install

Comment: that command appeared to run without errors, yet homebrew is still throwing out the error ``/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_support.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- checksums (LoadError)``

Comment: try `rvm pkg install zlib`

Comment: I believe I've figured out the solution.  Thank you so much for your time!